# Can I copy my Open Graph configuration between apps?

Tags: configuration, facebook-opengraph

Is there any way to export you open graph settings, or copy them between apps?

We have domain names that we used to deploy our code to before it goes into production.

```
http://dev-mysite.blah.com
http://int-mysite.blah.com
http://preprod-mysite.blah.com
http://mysite.blah.com
```

We have setup facebook apps for each of these domain names. And now I need to configure each of these apps to have Open Graph actions and objects. It seems like a pretty common scenario so what do you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, currently you have to do this manually.

However, you can rationalise it down to two app ids - one for production, and the other for all pre-prod and dev environments. This should cut down the work.